# Large jwt token payload python

Tags: python, jwt

I have large payload with 160 counts of dict in the list.

Example:

```
payload = [`enter code here`{'display_name': u'View',
           'id': 1,
'permission_name': u'myView'}]
```

So i have to send this payload as Json Web Token, from Django site. JWT is keep giving me error of

> Expecting a mapping object, as JWT only supports JSON objects as payloads

While using following code

```
jwt.encode(payload, 'secret', algorithm='HS256')
```

While i am using PyJWT package. I have tried convert that payload as json.dumps(payload) still same error.

Comment: Please include your Python code that you use to create a JWT from this.

Comment: included and i found the solution as well.

Comment: post the solution as answer :)

Comment: @Petar posted the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution for this to give a dictionary object and then convert it as a token.

Solution:

```
payload = [
  {
    'display_name': u'View',
    'id': 1,
    'permission_name': u'myView'
  }
]

jwt.encode({'data': payload}, 'secret', algorithm='HS256')
```

This will generate the token.

Comment: Actually this is still wrong. JWT has a certain definition on payload claims. What you need is JWS.